# update latest Security patch leads my ASP.NET system auto logout

Tags: asp.net, cookies, flex3, samesite

Operation system of my server is Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, and i updated latest security patch - KB4533012 on it, after the update, my ASP.NET system has a feature that post a request to a Flex grid, then display the swf grid in my aspx page, then i found the session was lost( using Fiddler), system was logout then whatever i did any actions.

what i found is a new property - SameSite has been supported in the new patch, the issue would be fixed if i uninstall the patch.

is there a bug between ASP.NET and Flex grid by using SameSite in http cookie?

appreciate for the help!

Answer (score 0):

the issue has been fixed by editing Web.config file following the steps:

1. add sameSite = "None" to httpCookies
2. add cookieSameSite = "None" to FormsAuthticaiton and SessionState